# How to replace material on multiple objects?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

My task is to import the same car into the scene several times and make them differ in color. But the fact is that a car consists of many parts that are different objects. Some machine parts have several material slots at once.

When I do it manually, I select the part, duplicate the material, change the color in it. Next, I select the next part, change the material to the one just created by duplication. And so on until I sort out all the details of this car.

Is there a way to make it faster? I need to change colors in this way for 20 cars.

Comment: Why import the car several times? Why not import only once set up materials, save it,  then modify only the colors that changed?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I meant import not from obj, fbx or other third party formats. I meant append or link. Or, for example, as an asset from the asset browser.

Comment: Let's say I imported the model into the scene once. How do I make multiple duplicates of this car but with different colors?